# Returning All the Values based on the Exact Lookups

Tags: excel

I have a table that contains "Lookup" and "Result" columns. My goal is find a formula that can return all the values from the "Result" column which lookup contains a specific string, and store these values into a cell. Below is the example:

[image]

Is there a way to solve this?

I have tried using **Index Match** and **Vlookup**, but both can only return the first matched value from the "Result" column.

Comment: If you want the result in one cell like you've shown then it is not possible using formulas alone. VBA UDF can do it.

Comment: You should be able to do it with formula if you have Excel 2016/365

Comment: you can do it using VBA UDF. check this https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2706-excel-vlookup-return-multiple-values-in-one-cell.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it would be this if you do have Excel 2016 / Office 365

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF($A$2:$A$10=D2,$B$2:$B$10,""))
```

entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

Comment: It works! Didn't know about "TEXTJOIN" function before. Thank you Tom.